# How to detect mysql server down status quickly

Tags: c++, mysql, c, api

I have an application which connects a remote database server.

If mysql server stops for a reason and stars succesfully after that, my application cannot detect server status quickly. It takes nearly 20 seconds to reconnect to the database server. So my gui freezes. I do not want a gui freeze for 20 seconds

So far I tried

- mysql_ping
- mysql_real_connect

functions

- MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT
- MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT

  options

My enviroment is not multi-threaded. So
how to do a faster detection?

Comment: When does it freeze? During inactivity or a query hangs?

Comment: Put queries in a separate process, and use IPC? Is there a reason your system can't be threaded? All modern systems with a GUI usually have threading functionality in the OS, even very small embedded systems (where threads are usually replaced by processes but without memory protection so the processes can be used as threads.)

Comment: @KirilKirov Freezes during reconnect attempt

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Using IPC or multi-threading solves gui freeze issue but not solves faster detection issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you do networking synchronously, be prepared for freezes. For this very reason it makes sense to do data-manipulation in a separate thread.

Comment: There is no data manipulation in my condition. I just want to check mysql server status

Comment: As I said to Joachim: Using IPC or multi-threading solves gui freeze issue but not solves faster detection issue.

Comment: The latency comes as a sum of: call to MySQL library preparing the request, TCP stack latency, network latency, TCP stack again at MySQL server, delay while MySQL is parsing the request, TCP stack while answering back, network latency once again, TCP stack at your computer, library function validating and returning the value to your application. Unless the MySQL server is stuck under heavy load, network latency dominates the overall delay.

Answer (score 0):

You could try telnet to the mysql port (usually 3306).  If you get a connection refused, mysql isn't listening.

Working.

```
root@XXXXXX:~# telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
L
5.6.4-m7)#m#_8:W�hP5YBzaXs[MOmysql_native_password
```

Down.

```
root@XXXXXX:~# telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

The refused message is almost instant.

Comment: This might still take time, depending on where the server is. Especially if a network cable is removed.

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed by others, i won't talk about using multiple threads or processes. Can you connect to your mysql server on tcp? That way in most scenario's you would receive a tcp fin immediately to indicate a closed connection, though at times this might not be the case even. But most robust applications do a proper close.

```
shell> mysql --protocol=TCP
```

[MYSQL how to specify protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html)

If server doesn't accept it, i believe it can be enabled from config settings.

However, this does not address scenarios such as server suddenly gets off the network, or you client's connection is down etc.